# mounting drive on remote location using sh command

Tags: linux, mount

What does the command `sh mount_drive.sh` means?

I am trying to mount a drive located at a remote location onto my server using the above command. Previously it worked fine but now it is giving an error

> mount error 6 =no such device or address

Comment: It runs a script named `mount_drive.sh` which we would need to see in order to know what it does.

Answer (score 2):

So the command `sh mount_drive.sh` is referring to a shell script that has a list of commands to execute.

So the line `mount error 6 = no such device or address` is stating that there is an issue with one of the lines in the script. It may be pointing to an IP address that is no longer in use.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking up your command, the `sh` part refers to a shell. The second part, `mount_drive.sh`, is the shell script that has the list of commands to run. What you can do to help this question is type `cat mount_drive.sh` and copy the output into your question.

Mount errors mean that nothing will mount with that command. If this is an SMB mount, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13835629/50544) answer may help. You will need to edit your script though if you need to make corrections. You can use `pico`, `emacs`, or `vi`/`vim` to do so. As an example, I would type `vim mount_drive.sh` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>